# Transitting through Spanish Airport-customs rules

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, local-customs, vat

I will be arriving to Barcelona on a flight from the US. 22 hours later I will have to catch my flight to Russia from Barcelona. I have a question regarding my imported goods then.

I am in transit and a resident of Russia. I have a Swedish passport as well, so there is no need for visa.  I expect to carry goods with total value of 1000€ for further transportation to Russia. I will have to go through Spanish customs when I arrive in Barcelona.

Are there any solutions in my case? Maybe I could leave my expensive goods at the airport customs office for storing until next day when I fly to Russia, or I can just show the goods again to the customs staff when I am flying out to prove I am exporting the goods outside EU.

What should I do?

Comment: Businesses involved in the regular import and export of goods use a "bonded warehouse" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonded_warehouse) to hold goods in one country (without paying customs), for eventual transshipment to other countries. These warehouses are licensed and bonded, and essentially trusted by the county's customs authorities to hold goods and not release them into the country's economy. You're endeavoring to do the same (a temporary import without paying customs), but I don't know how to accomplish it on this much smaller scale. Perhaps others will have suggestions for you.

Comment: Did you check whether Barcelona airport has left luggage airside and whether you will be able to get your luggage on your outward journey? I am not sure whether it will work but it might be possible.

Comment: @Willeke Left luggage would have to be available (inbound) before the OP passes Customs, which seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: I know Schiphol, (AMS, Amsterdam) has lockers airside, I do not know what other airports have.

Comment: Airside lockers or storage will only be useful to the OP is he’s carrying the property in his carry-on, and not in checked luggage.

Comment: True, I forgot that might be the case.